# Como fazer um script em python executar dois processos simultaneamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

A pouco tempo aprendi a capturar vídeos através da webcam usando Python com a biblioteca OpenCV. Após isso, tive a ideia de fazer um script que inicie e encerre automaticamente a gravação de um vídeo. Iniciado o programa, a captura iniciaria, mas só começaria a gravar se o frame capturado satisfizesse determinada condição que eu criei (baseado em uma função de detecção que eu fiz). A gravação do vídeo encerraria automaticamente quando os frames capturados não contivessem o que a função detectora está programada para detectar. A função detectora retorna True se a imagem satisfizer minha condição e False se não satisfizer. O script é o seguinte:

```
def webvideo(path):
    import sys,cv2
    begin=False
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print('Não foi possível abrir a web cam.')
        sys.exit(-1)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(path,fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite('temp.jpg',frame)
            if not begin:
                if funcao_detectora('temp.jpg'):
                    begin=True
            else:
                if not funcao_detectora('temp.jpg'):
                    break
            if begin:
                out.write(frame)
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()

webvideo('teste.avi')
```

O problema é que a função detectora lê cada frame, o que leva um tempo. Assim, leva um tempo para que o próximo frame seja capturado e o vídeo fica como se fosse uma sequência de fotos bastante espaçadas temporalmente. Pergunta: como faço pra rodar a função detectora em um processo diferente do processo da gravação dos frames para que os frames sejam gravados sem interrupção?

OBS: não é necessário aplicar o conhecimento de multithreading para solucionar esse caso em específico, mas se alguém mostrar um exemplo que eu entenda e possa aplicar no meu script, também vou aceitar.

Comment: Uma "intuição" é você não processar imediatamente cada quadro do vídeo, mas colocá-lo em uma lista pra ser processada quando der (idealmente, em uma thread separada mesmo). Se eu tiver tempo hoje eu vejo se consigo responder.

Comment: Não acho que seja necessário armazenar cada frame em uma lista, acho que basta criar uma função que faça a função detectora ler cada frame e fazer essa função rodar em um processo diferente. Porém não sei como faz isso. Tentei ler a documentação do modulo multiprocessing, mas além de ser iniciante na área, não sei muito inglês e acabo entendendo muito pouco.

Comment: Bom, o seu problema hoje é justamente o fato de que o seu processamento dos quadros demora mais do que a captura deles. Se você usar outra thread mas bloqueá-la em uma chamada entre threads, o seu resultado final vai ser o mesmo: quadros "pulados".

Comment: Ah, outra coisa: eu usei uma *thread* diferente, e não um processo diferente. Ou seja, roda tudo no mesmo processo, mas de forma paralela. Creio que fazer multiprocesso nesse caso é equivocado, pois haverá uma comunicação frequente de dados potencialmente grande (os quadros do vídeo, além de ser capturados 20x por segundo, têm 480 mil pixels - sendo conservador e considerando uma resolução baixíssima de 800x600).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis um exemplo de código que faz a leitura em uma thread separada. A ideia de armazenar os quadros lidos em uma lista (que, na prática, funciona como uma [fila FIFO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)) é porque o seu processamento dos quadros recebidos na thread principal vai levar mais tempo do que a captura, por isso você não deve impedir que a captura ocorra.

> Observações:
>
> 1. Note que no seu sistema final, você deveria ser capaz de processar o restante dos quadros ainda "enfileirados" após o sistema ser
>      encerrado. Esse exemplo **não faz isso**, ele apenas ilustra como
>      trabalhar com as duas threads e uma fila entre elas.
> 2. O Python tem uma classe [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), que é uma fila com prioridades, limitação de tamanho e outros detalhes. É bom saber que ela existe,
>      mas nesse exemplo era desnecessário.

```
import sys
import threading
import cv2

# ==========================================
class WebcamError(ValueError):
    pass

# ==========================================
class WebcamCap(threading.Thread):

    # --------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, webcam = 0):
        super().__init__(None, self)

        self._webcam = webcam
        '''Id da Webcam a ser utilizada. O default é 0 (principal).'''

        self._video = cv2.VideoCapture(self._webcam)
        '''Objeto para captura do vídeo.'''

        if not self._video.isOpened():
            raise WebcamError('Não foi possível iniciar a Webcam.')

        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        '''Mutex usado para a sincronização entre as threads.'''

        self._frames = []
        '''Lista de quadros capturados e aptos a serem processados.'''

        self._started = threading.Event()
        '''Evento usado para controlar a inicialização da câmera.'''

        self._running = False
        '''Flag usada para indicar e controlar se a Thread está em execução.'''

    # --------------------------------------
    def __del__(self):
        self._video.release()

    # --------------------------------------
    def start(self):
        if not self.isRunning():
            super().start()
            # Aguarda até que a câmera seja inicializada corretamente
            self._started.clear()
            self._started.wait()

    # --------------------------------------
    def stop(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        self._running = False
        self._lock.release()

    # --------------------------------------
    def isRunning(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        ret = self._running
        self._lock.release()
        return ret

    # --------------------------------------
    def pop(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        try:
            frame = self._frames.pop()
        except:
            frame = None
        self._lock.release()
        return frame

    # --------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        # Força a leitura do primeiro quadro, já que a inicialização da câmera
        # demora um pouco
        ret, frame = self._video.read()
        if ret:
            self._frames.append(frame)
            self._running = True
            self._started.set() # Evento indicando a inicialização
        else:
            raise WebcamError('Não foi possível acessar a Webcam.')

        # Loop principal de leitura
        while self.isRunning():
            ret, frame = self._video.read()
            if ret:
                self._lock.acquire()
                self._frames.append(frame)
                self._lock.release()

# ==========================================
def webvideo(path):

    fps = 20 # Taxa de reprodução (em quadros por segundo)
    delay = int(1 / fps * 1000) # Tempo de 1 quadro em milisegundos

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, fps, (640,480))

    try:
        cam = WebcamCap()
    except WebcamError as e:
        print(e.message)
        sys.exit(-1)

    cam.start()
    while True:

        frame = cam.pop()
        if frame is not None:
            out.write(frame)

            cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(delay) == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print('Erro capturando video da Webcam')
            break

    cam.stop()
    out.release()

webvideo('teste.avi')
```