# Como criar um método que pause e um que retome uma Thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, multithreading

O seguinte script mostra a variável x de 3 em 3 segundos, enquanto a classe xx, que está sendo executada em uma thread, vai aumentando o valor de x a cada segundo. Gostaria que, quando o valor de x chegasse a 13, a thread onde a classe xx está sendo executada parasse.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class xx(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global x
        while True:
            x+=1
            sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        #O que botar aqui para parar a execução da thread?

    def play(self):
        #O que botar aqui para iniciar a thread depois de pausada?



x=0

instx=xx()
instx.start()

while True:
    sleep(3)
    print(x)
    if x==13:
        instx.stop()
```

Porém não sei o que pôr nos métodos stop(self) e play(self) para pausar e retomar a execução da thread. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Em uma das respostas que eu dei *justamente em uma pergunta sua*, eu faço exatamente o que vc quer aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178303/73 Você chegou a estudar o código naquela ocasião? Porque parece que não, né? Bem, a resposta é simples: use uma variável de controle no laço do seu `while`. Outra coisa pra pensar: "stop" é bem diferente de "pause". Boa sorte!

Comment: É verdade. Confesso que na época não havia entendido bem todo o script porque estava iniciando meu estudo sobre threads. Agora vejo mais claramente. E obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há muita mágica possível, além de alguns cuidados com dados compartilhados entre as várias threads.

Na sua thread filha, o único código rodando é o que está na função "run" - 
e todos os outros métodos na verdade, so código executado na thread principal, que cria as threads filhas.

Então, qualquer coisa que você quiser fazer que tenha efeitos no que está rodando na thread filha, tem que ser feito no código que é executao na thread -

Uma vez que você tem lá um `while True:`, ou seja, um codigo que fica em loop, em uma lina desse while você deve ou verificar, ou chamar uma função que verifica, dados alterados na função principal.

Com isso, e com o uso de Queue, Locks, Events e Semaphores, descritos em https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html você pode controlar a comunicação bidirecional de forma efetiva entre uma thread principal e uma secundária, ou entre a thread principal e um conjunto (pool) de threas secundárias coordenadas.

Em particular, os objetos do tipo "Lock" podem ser "a forma correta" de se fazer o que você quer fazer com os métodos "stop" e "play" aí. 
Mas para responder de forma simples, o que se faria seria configurar um objeto do tipo "Event" - ele é algo bem simples do modulo threading, que tem uma chamada `wait` que bloqueia, e só retorna a execução quando o objeto é ativado com a chamada a `.set()`, em alguma outra thread.

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
from time import sleep

class xx(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self._active = Event()
        self._active.set()
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global x
        while True:
            self._active.wait()
            x+=1
            sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.active.clear()

    def play(self):
        self.active.set()
```