# Phyton aguardar pause

Tags: python

Quero automatizar uma tarefa, como o software não possui api que permita isto, vou controlar o mouse do OS e clicar usando Phyton.

Pretendo criar validações com imagens para garantir que estou na tela certa e clicando no lugar certo, mesmo assim gostaria de uma proteção extra, que seria parar a execução ao presionar P no teclado e continuar ao clicar U.

- Minha dúvida é, se tem como fazer isto sem ter que repetir a verificação a cada linha do programa, aguardar o click e parar a execução ao receber a info do usuário.

Sou novo com Phyton, primeira tentativa.

**Editado**

Ajustando a pergunta para atender algumas dúvidas colocadas pelo @jsbueno:

- Estou usando Windows 10.
- É um programa apenas com linhas de código, editadas no VSCODE.
- Estou importando pyautogui (ainda não na verdade), curses e threading.

Agora pela manhã estive estudando sobre isto e já consegui algum resultado, está parando e continuando corretamente, porem ao dar o stop() para matar a thread, ele não libera o terminal, ele fica preso sem solicitar tecla nem nada, segue o código:

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
from time import sleep
import curses


class xx(Thread):
    _stop = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self._active = Event()
        self._active.set()
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global x
        global f
        y = 1
        while True:
            if self._stop != 0:
                return
            self._active.wait()
            x += 1
            y += 1
            sleep(1)
            f = open("output.txt", "a+")
            f.write("x: " + str(x) + " - y: " + str(y) + "\n")
            f.close()
            if x == 10:
                return

    def pause(self):
        self._active.clear()

    def play(self):
        self._active.set()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = 1


x = 0
f = open("output.txt", "w+")
f.write("Inicio\n")
f.close()


def main(win):
    f = open("output.txt", "a+")
    f.write("Main Start\n")
    f.close()
    instx = xx()
    instx.start()
    key = ""
    while True:
        win.clear()
        win.addstr("Detected key:")
        win.addstr(str(key))
        if key == 't':
            instx.stop()
            return
        elif key == 'p':
            instx.pause()
        elif key == 'u':
            instx.play()
        key = win.getkey()
    instx.join()


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Estou tendo dificuldade para debuggar o programa, o que vocês desenvolvedores Python usam para isto ?

E se vocês tiverem alguma dica de livro ou curso para iniciar na linguagem fico grato.

Para gerar o código acima, peguei informações nas seguintes fontes:

Trabalhar com thread
* [Como criar um método que pause e um que retome uma Thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183601/como-criar-um-m%c3%a9todo-que-pause-e-um-que-retome-uma-thread?rq=1)
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063963/python-is-thread-still-running
* https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/

Teclado pressionado
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Trabalhar com arquivos ( para debug )
* https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html

Concatenar string e int
* https://www.journaldev.com/23642/python-concatenate-string-and-int

Comment: se vocẽ está usando "threading", nada vai conseguir debugar o programa. Sem threads, é só por um "breakpoint()" e acompanhar a execução pelo terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Resumindo: no fim das contas, sim, pra isso que você quer, vai ter que chamar uma função pra verificar o teclado entre cada linha do programa.

é bem difícil dar uma resposta concreta para uma pergunta abstrata.
Você não disse nada sobra a interface que vai usar para o seu programa - 
Para poder vaidar imagens da tela, controlar o mouse, e etc...assumo que você estará usando o `pyautogui` que é uma biblioteca que faz isso.

Também, pelo texto da pergunta, assumo que é um programa sem nenhuma interface gráfica, apenas com várias linhas com uma chamada à biblioteca que gera eventos de teclado/mouse após a outra.

Em programas com interface gráfica - como tkinter, ou Qt, o próprio framework disponibiliza um mecanismo de detecção de eventos e meios para uma função sua ser chamada quando o teclado for usado.  Num programa sem interface gráfica, você é responsável por isso -e ainda, para ler o teclado em tempo real tem que usar uma biblioteca como `curses` ou alguma outra.

Aliás, você não disse nem se está no Windows, Linux ou MacOS - o controle do teclado no terminal, e compatibilidade de bibliotecas muda entre esses sistemas - deixa a resposta mais difícil ainda.

De qualquer forma, mesmo num framework de interface gráfica, em geral, as linhas dentro de uma função são executadas semre uma após a outra, sem interrupção.

A solução - com ou sem interface gráfica, parece ser você se aproveitar do fato de que quer fazer uma pausa entre um comando e outro, e escrever uma função que faça a pausa, verificando sempre o teclado. (Fui olhar a doc do pyautogui, ele sozinho não tem nada para ler o teclado - apenas para enviar teclas).

Mas então, vamos supor que você esteja usando a função `time.sleep` para dar uma pausa entre os seus comandos - o seu programa já seria algo assim:

```
funcao_pra_clicar_em_ok()
time.sleep(0.5)
funcao_para_preencher_campo_nome()
funcao_para_preencher_senha()
time.sleep(0.2)
funcao_para_clicar_em_ok()
```

A saída é você ciraruma outra função pra pausa, depois de achar uma funcao que verifica o teclado em tempo real no seu ambiente, e em vez de chamar o time.sleep direto, chamar uma função como:

```
def pausa(tempo_total):
   inicio = time.time()
   passo = 0.05
   while True:
      teclas = verifica_teclas()
      if teclas["P"]:
          # codigo para pausa
      ...
      if time.time() - inicio >= tempo_total:
          break
      time.sleep(passo)
```

(há sim, formas de se evitar ter que chamar a função de pausa a cada linha, mas seria algo bem sofisticado - veja se consegue trazer mais dados sobre o seu ambiente, e talvez seja possível melhorar a resposta)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pelo feedback referente a qualidade da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

## Sobre uma Pattern para intercalar uma chamada de função a cada linha

Coloquei considerações gerais sobre o seu problema na outra resposta.
Para abordar mais diretamente a questão de "como repetir uma tarefa após cada linha de código", preferi abrir outra resposta -

Mesmo com frameworks que tem laços de evento, ou um programa multi-threading, é bem difícil garantir que um determinado código vai ser executado após cada "trecho de execução".

Laços de eventos em Frameworks como o tkinter e Qt só vão verificar eventos quando sua função terminar. Threads não dão garantia nenhuma de quando a verificação é feita. Na verdade, a grande "mudança de paradigma" para programação assíncrona - que introduziu toda uma forma diferente de programar a partir do Python 3.4 (e novas palavras chave a partir do Python 3.5), é justamente poder dizer, dentro de uma função, em *quais pontos* a execução da função pode ser "pausada" para outro código em paralelo poder rodar. Isso essencialmente é o que o "asyncio" faz, todas as outras formas ou só vão mudar para o outro código (o que verifica os eventos) no final da função, ou vão mudar em que vocễ tenha controle nenhum sobre isso (podendo acontecer a mudança ou não).

O módulo `asyncio` permitiria organizar a pausa+verificação em cada passo do seu programa, mas você teria que restruturar todo o seu programa para funcionar com o mesmo, e transformar todas as suas chamadas que fazem o passo a passo da tarefa em co-rotinas. Ai o seu corpo do programa teria que colocar a palavra chave `await` antes de cada chamada. (E mesmo assim ainda daria um trabalinho acertar para a verificação do teclado realmente ser executada com uma pausa)

Usar asyncio não é o que eu recomendaria nesse caso. Coloco um exemplo no final da cara que o código teria.

## Colocar as tarefas a serem chamadas numa estrutura de dados

A forma mais simples e menos repetitiva de executar várias tarefas e garantir que algum código seja executado entre cada uma, pode ser especificar as tarefas  como dados em uma lista, em vez de linhas de programa - e aí ter algum código que coordene as chamadas das tarefas.

Então, em vez do código assim:

```
def executar()

    funcao_pra_clicar_em_ok(parametro1, parametro2)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    verificar_teclas()
    funcao_para_preencher_campo_nome()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    verificar_teclas() 
    funcao_para_preencher_senha()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    verificar_teclas() 
    funcao_para_clicar_em_ok()
```

Pode-se aproveitar que em Python, funções são objetos como qualquer outro, e podem ser tratados como dados até o momento de serem chamadas -e aí você pode escrever algo assim:

```py
# Tarefas a serem executadas, como uma lista em que 
# cada elemento é uma sequência com a função a ser chamada
# e os parâmetros a passar:

lista_de_tarefas = [
   (funcao_para_clicar_em_ok, (parametro1, parametro2)),
   (funcao_para_preencher_campo_nome, ()),
   (funcao_para_preencher_senha, ()),
   (funcao_para_clicar_em_ok, ()),
]

def executar(tarefas):
    for tarefa in tarefas():
       tarefa[0](*tarefa[1])
       pausa()
       verifica_teclas()

executar(lista_de_tarefas)
```

## exemplo com Asyncio

Usando asyncio o código poderia ficar algo como:

```py
encerrado = False
async def main():
    global encerrado
    
    await funcao_pra_clicar_em_ok()
    await funcao_para_preencher_campo_nome()
    await funcao_para_preencher_senha()
    await funcao_para_clicar_em_ok()

    encerrado = True

async def pausas():
   while not encerrado:
       teclas = verifica_teclado()
       if pressionado("P", teclas):
            # codigo de pausa
            ...
       time.sleep(0.5)  # Pausa real de 0.5 segundo
       await asyncio.sleep(0)  # Pausa falsa pra forçar mudança de contexto asyncio.

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
def start(loop):
    await loop.gather([main(), pausas()])
    
loop.run_until_complete(start())
```